# Aligning text of different sizes on different levels

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align text of different sizes on different levels. See the image below to see what I want:

[image]

Here is the code I'm trying but it does not seem to work.

```css
div {
  background: #1FA3A2;
  padding: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span style="vertical-align:text-top; font-size:14px;">$</span>
  <span style="font-size:30px; vertical-align:top;">199</span>
  <span style="font-size:14px; vertical-align:bottom;">/month</span>
</div>
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: your code aligns it properly, what's your problem?

Comment: In his image the tip of the `$` doesn't go higher than the top of `799`. And the `/mo` doesn't go any lower than the bottom of `799`. If you render his code, you'll see the `$` goes higher than the top of `799` and the `/month` goes lower than the bottom of `799`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the line height of the spans as well, and therefore influence the vertical alignment.

```css
div {
  background: #1FA3A2;
  padding: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span style="vertical-align:top; font-size:14px;">$</span>
  <span style="font-size:30px; line-height:27px; vertical-align:bottom;">199</span>
  <span style="font-size:14px; line-height:16px; vertical-align:bottom;">/month</span>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the positions and top css attributes to solve the miner alignment issue in your code. See the updated code. Recommending to write the style alone (Instead of inline styles). The given style (`top: 'value';`) the following code may change based on the overall style which you are planing to give (same as like the picture with the question)

```
<div>
    <span class="dlr">$</span>
    <span style="font-size:30px; vertical-align:top;">199</span>
    <span class="perd" >/month</span>
</div>

.dlr{
  vertical-align:text-top;
  font-size:14px;
  position:relative;
  top:6px;}
.perd{
  font-size:14px; 
  vertical-align:bottom;
  position:relative;
  top:-4px;}
```

Here are the [Demo](http://codepen.io/fanafazil/pen/JYzZMe)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
.a{font-size:12px; vertical-align:text-top; }
.b{font-size:30px; vertical-align:middle}
.c{font-size:12px; vertical-align:sub;}
```

With:

```
<div>
    <span class="a">$</span>
    <span class="b">199</span>
    <span class="c">/month</span>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z03cynrp/1/

Answer (score 0):

HI now used to this `after` or `before` **css** property as like this

```css
div > span{
 position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;color:#fff;
}
div > span:after{
  position:absolute;
  content:"$";
    font-size:14px;
  top:4px;
  left:-6px;
}
div > span:before{
  position:absolute;
  content:"/month";
    font-size:14px;
  bottom:3px;
  right:-38px;
}
div{background:blue; padding:20px 0; text-align:center;}
```

```html
<div>
    <span style="font-size:30px; vertical-align:top;">199</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the fact that all the three of them do not have the same line-heights. I could modify your code to align as you wanted.

```css
span {
  line-height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span style="font-size:14px; vertical-align:text-bottom">$</span>
  <span style="font-size:30px;">199</span>
  <span style="font-size:14px;">/month</span>
</div>
```

PS: Dont use inline style unless you absolutely have to